# multiple file upload script is not working with asp.net file upload

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, asp.net

When i use HTML File Upload img are visible below file upload, but if i use asp file upload img are not visible.

[image: 1]

> when i use normal html file upload control then the java script is
> working fine but when use the script for asp.net file-upload then the
> java-script is not working.

**asp.net**

```
<div class="field" align="left">
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
```

> <asp:FileUpload runat="server"  id="files" name="files[]" multiple>
> </asp:FileUpload>

```
</div>
```

**java-script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#files").on("change", function (e) {
                    var files = e.target.files,
                      filesLength = files.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
                        var f = files[i]
                        var fileReader = new FileReader();
                        fileReader.onload = (function (e) {
                            var file = e.target;
                            $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
                              "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\""  + file.name + "\"/>" +
                              "<br/><span class=\"remove\">Remove image</span>" +
                              "</span>").insertAfter("#files");
                            $(".remove").click(function () {
                                $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
                            });

                            // Old code here
                            /*$("<img></img>", {
                              class: "imageThumb",
                              src: e.target.result,
                              title: file.name + " | Click to remove"
                            }).insertAfter("#files").click(function(){$(this).remove();});*/

                        });
                        fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
                    }
                    console.log(files);
                });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: did  you inspect the code while uploading multiple files ? what message do you get?

Comment: When i use HTML File Upload img are visible below file upload, but if i use asp file upload img are not visible.

Comment: use debugger in the on change js function to find out the what's missing ?